# Flexslider - How to make two slider functioning together (images and a paragraph text) using a single directionNav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

**My mark up is**

```
        <div class="slide_container">
             <div class='bg_container'>
                <div id='bg_slider' class='flexslider' >
                    <ul id='slide_set' class='slides'>
                        <li>image 1</li>
                        <li>image 2</li>
                        <li>image 3</li>
                        <li>image 4</li>            
                    </ul>
                    <div id='glass_div'></div> 
                </div>                    
            </div>
            <div class='tex_slide_container'>
                <div id='message' class='flexslider2'>
                    <ul id='content_slide_holder' class='slides'>
                        <li>
                            <div class='text_holder'>  
                                <div class='text_div'>text 1</div>
                            </div>                            
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class='text_holder'>  
                                <div class='text_div'>text 1</div>
                            </div>                           
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class='text_holder'>  
                                <div class='text_div'>text 1</div>
                            </div>                        
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class='text_holder'>  
                                <div class='text_div'>text 1</div>
                            </div>                         
                        </li>   
                    </ul>    
                </div>                    
            </div>                    
        </div>
```

**My JS script is : **

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#slide_row").show();
        var count = 0 ; 
        $("#loaing_animation").hide();

        $('.flexslider').flexslider(
        {
            animation: "slide",
            animationSpeed: 4000,
            easing: "swing",
            slideshowSpeed: 10000,
            touch:false,
            before: function(){
                if(count == 1 ){
                    $('#static_path').attr('id','moving_path');
                    $('.empty_wings').attr('class','wings');
                    $('.empty_body').attr('class','birdbody');
                }
                count++;                                              
            },
            after: function(){
            },controlNav: false,
            directionNav: true


        }           
    );
        $('.flexslider2').flexslider(
        {
            animation: "slide",
            animationSpeed: 2500,
            easing: "swing",
            slideshowSpeed: 10000,
            touch:false,
            before: function(){
            },
            after: function(){
            },
            controlNav: false,
            directionNav: true
        }           
    );          
    });
</script>
```

**my css is :**
[here](http://gsecanopy.com/3003/slider.css)

I am not willing to change the mark up.

The situation is after I enable the **directionNav** if I click the Nav button the images are sliding, not the paragraph.

I am trying to slide both texts (text holder) and the image together.

How can I do that?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can u make a fiddle ..?

Comment: jsfiddle [link](jsfiddle.net/‎)??[Link] can't we do without changing the script?

Comment: See when u enable the navigation, flexslider add the anchor tag with class, and u have 2 flexslider they add it 2 times so which one slider html comes first in DOM, that is scrolling on nav click .. best u add ur own naviation button and on there click call flexslider.gotoSlide() methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own nex/prev (u can add navigator image etc as per ur requirement these is just for demo how nex/prev can work.) 
As if 2 flexslider navigation html  will be conflict. and only one will be navigate.

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5QSEb/1/)

```
  $("#next").on("click" , function (e) { 
     var $slider = flex1.data('flexslider');        
    $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("next"), true);  
    var $slider = flex2.data('flexslider');
     $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("next"), true);     
  });

  $("#prev").on("click" , function (e) { 
     var $slider = flex1.data('flexslider');        
    $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("prev"), true);  
    var $slider = flex2.data('flexslider');
     $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("prev"), true);     
  });
```

Comment: thank you so much for you help and time spending.. but when click the next or prev button nothing happening. next oe prev appears like a normal text.

Comment: yup.. its working on fiddle.. 1. I copied your just and paste it in to my html file. 2. I've added `<div id="next"> Next </div> <div id="prev" > Prev </div>` in to my mark up area.. when I preview it's showing the next / prev text. but when I click nothing happening.. :(

Comment: did u copy js changes also .. and r u using flex2 js as its referring

Comment: It's working.. I put your mark up in a wrong place previously... thanks a lot.. it's a great favor..

Comment: cool it works..slideshow false make it auto loop stop bcaz that will conflict with custom nav.

Comment: I've changed it to `true`. so when page loads the slide show starts automatically.. you are great.. thanks a lot