# flexslider - two sliders together - Directional Nav sliding only one slider some times. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I am using two sliders together.
One for images - .flexslider
another one for text - .flexslider2

for both sliders I am using a single directional Nav.
[FIDDLE DEMO OS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/W9Utq/1/)

```
        $(window).load(function() {
    $("#slide_row").show();
    var count = 0 ; 

    $("#loaing_animation").hide();

$("#next").on("click" , function (e) { 
     var $slider = flex1.data('flexslider');

    $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("next"), true);  
    var $slider = flex2.data('flexslider');
     $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("next"), true); 

});

 $("#prev").on("click" , function (e) { 
     var $slider = flex1.data('flexslider');

    $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("prev"), true);  
    var $slider = flex2.data('flexslider');
     $slider.flexAnimate($slider.getTarget("prev"), true); 

});

  var flex1 =  $('.flexslider').flexslider(
    {
        animation: "slide",
        animationSpeed: 4000,
        easing: "swing",
        slideshowSpeed: 10000,
        touch:false,
        before: function(){
            if(count == 1 ){
                $('#static_path').attr('id','moving_path');
                $('.empty_wings').attr('class','wings');
                $('.empty_body').attr('class','birdbody');
            }
            count++;                                              
        },
        after: function(){
        },controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow:true


    }           
);
var flex2=    $('.flexslider2').flexslider(
    {
        animation: "slide",
        animationSpeed: 2500,
        easing: "swing",
        slideshowSpeed: 10000,
        touch:false,
        before: function(){
        },
        after: function(){
        },
        controlNav: false,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow:true
    }           
);          
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO IS HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/riffaz/W9Utq/1/)

1st three slides are working fine when I click next or prev button.
4th or there after if click the next / prev button image is sliuder not the text.

I suspect it's because of the slider animation speed.
**.flexslider animation speed = 4000 and .flexslider2 animation speed = 2500**

any how I could not fix this.
how can I fix this?

any help will be appreciated.

** this question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345782/flexslider-how-to-make-two-slider-funtioning-together-images-and-a-paragraph)

Comment: Have you tried changing the animation speed so that they're the same?

Comment: yup.. if both sliders animation speed are same, then it's working fine. no problem... but I need to keep those setting. two flexsliders with two animation speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest animation will be ready first than others, so if you click on `next` in this time only the fastest slide will change.

I added a flag `isAnimating` in your code and changed de functions `before` and `after` to set this flag.

Take a look in <kbd>[**your code updated**](http://jsfiddle.net/W9Utq/2/)</kbd>

Comment: thanks a lot Fernando.. it's working like a charm. you the savor and please do not remove that updated fiddle for some days..

Comment: I forked the fiddle to my account to make sure the code will not be disabled... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandosavio/MJMn3/)

Comment: thanks for that Fernando. I too forked it. I've noticed another issue.. if I work some tabs while the slide show is in another tab, if I come to slide show tab (after finish work on other tabs - 1rount 45 second to 2 minuts) the slide show showing the wrong combination of slides. eg: image3, text2